# Access a text file in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read the contents of a flat file stored in the phone's memory. But when I get the file address through the attempt, and I create the File object this is not readable.

Try to create it by manually passing the file's address and it works.

The problem is that I can not get that address from the uri that gives me the Intent

Here I open the android file browser

```
btnAdjuntar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige App");
            if (chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(chooser, COD_ABRIR_FICHERO);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I receive the Intent

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == COD_ABRIR_FICHERO) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String ruta = data.getData().getPath();
            String lectura;
            try {
                lectura = leerArchivo(ruta);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                lectura = e.getMessage();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lectura, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown and you have this message:
/document/primary:Documents/PruebaArchivo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Method leerArchivo

```
public String leerArchivo(String ruta) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String cadena;
    String lectura = "";

    File file = new File(ruta);
    FileReader f = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
    while ((cadena = b.readLine()) != null) {
        lectura += cadena;
    }
    b.close();
    return lectura;
}
```

Already the permissions to read the external memory are accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open an InputStream from a Uri:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Then wrap the input stream to create a BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while ((cadena = b.readLine()) != null) {
    lectura += cadena;
}
b.close();
```

etc.

This way you never need to get the file's address. You can specify the encoding (e.g. "UTF-8") as a second parameter to the InputStreamReader constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

> But when I get the file address through the attempt, and I create the File object this is not readable.

You are not getting a file. You are getting content. You are being given a `Uri`. A `Uri` is not a file.

```
String ruta = data.getData().getPath();
```

That line is only useful if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. In your case, the scheme is probably `content`.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content. This works whether the `Uri` has a `file` scheme or a `content` scheme.